# Misalignment when using "adj" in title() for an R plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to have my titles be above my points in a pdf plot.  It seems R thinks my title is wider than my plot area even though I have my right and left plot margins set to zero.

```
x <- seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)
xtitle <- c("0.1","0.2","0.3","0.4","0.5","0.6","0.7","0.8","0.9")

pdf("testpdfopts.pdf", width = 16)
par(mar = c(0, 0, 1, 0))      # only need margin at top for title
plot(
    x,
    rep(0.9,length(x)),
    xlim = c(0, 1),
    ylim = c(0, 1),
    cex = 1,
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n",
    xlab = "",
    ylab = ""
)

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    title(xtitle[i],adj=x[i],cex.main=1)
}
dev.off()
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sort of confused with what you are trying to do. Maybe I should put my comment into complete code:

```
x <- seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)

plot(
    x,
    rep(0.9,length(x)),
    xlim = c(0, 1),
    ylim = c(0, 1),
    cex = 1,
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n",
    xlab = "",
    ylab = ""
)

axis(3, at = 1:9/10)
```

[image]

Is this equivalent to what you aim to achieve?

---

You can get character labels too:

```
x <- seq(from = 0.1, to = 0.9, by = 0.1)

plot(
    x,
    rep(0.9,length(x)),
    xlim = c(0, 1),
    ylim = c(0, 1),
    cex = 1,
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n",
    xlab = "",
    ylab = ""
)

axis(3, at = 1:9/10, labels = letters[1:9])
```

[image]

Comment: No, sorry, I'm new, my example was bad.  The titles will be the names - a character field, of the points below.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.